# Outerplanar graph

Tags: graph-theory

Show that for an [outerplanar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph), $G =(p,q)$, where $p$ is the number of vertices and $q$ is the number of edges,
$q$ is less than or equal to $2p - 3$.

I tried some examples and it worked. But not sure how to approach the proof. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have some outerplanar graph $G(p,q)$. We can insert edges to get a triangularized version of $G$, say $G'(p,q')$. For $G'$, all faces except the outer face are triangles. From the handshaking lemma, we have
$$2q' = \sum_{f'\in F(G')}\deg(f') = 3(|F(G')|-1)+p=3(1+q'-p)+p$$
Which implies 
$$2p = 3 + q' \ge 3 + q$$